Why don't we typically worry about stationarity in panel data models with fixed effects?
Why don't we typically worry about stationarity in panel data models with fixed effects?
In time series analysis, stationarity is often a crucial assumption. However, I've noticed that in applied microeconometrics with panel data, researchers seem less concerned about whether the variables $y_{it}$ and $x_{it}$ are stationary.
Consider a typical fixed effects model:
$$y_{it} = \alpha_i + \alpha_t + \sum_{l=1}^L \beta_l x_{i,t-l} + \epsilon_{it}$$
In this context, we often don't seem to care whether:

$y_{it}$ satisfies traditional stationarity assumptions

The covariance structure $Cov(y_{it}, y_{i,t+k})$ is time-invariant

The conditional expectation $E[y_{it}|\alpha_i,\alpha_t]$ is
independent of $t$


This stands in contrast to the VAR literature, where stationarity plays a central role.
Why can we often ignore stationarity in panel data contexts?
Is there something about having large $N$ (cross-sectional units) that makes stationarity less crucial?
Can someone provide an intuitive explanation, with some mathematical reasoning if possible? I'm familiar with basic panel data methods and time series concepts, but I'm trying to understand this specific distinction between the two fields' treatment of stationarity.
